# Windows Phone 8.1 Live SDK 5.6 Login issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, live-sdk, onedrive

I am following the Windows Live SDK 5.6 example codes and have my own simple app trying to login OneDrive. With my Microsoft account given step by step, seems everything is fine, however, i always get System.NullReferenceException, when application goes to this page again, when i click the single button:

```
private async void signInBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("authClient = " + authClient);

            loginResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.photos" });

            if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {

                liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(loginResult.Session);
                var meResult = await liveClient.GetAsync("me");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(meResult.Result["name"].ToString() + ", " + "You have logged in OneDrive!");
            }

        }
        catch (LiveAuthException authExp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LiveAuthException = " + authExp.ToString());
        }

        catch (LiveConnectException connExp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LiveConnectException = " + connExp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

it throws exception at this line:

```
loginResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.photos" });
```

Anything goes wrong in my codes? Even referred to the sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a list instead of a String array:

```cs
public static async Task<LiveLoginResult> LoginAsync()
{
    List<String> oneDriveScopes = new List<String>() { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive_update" };
    LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
    LiveLoginResult authResult;
    try
    {
        authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(oneDriveScopes);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return authResult;
}
```

Comment: Did you try exactly that code I posted and did you still get that same Exception when you called the LoginAsync method? That method I wrote is working fine for me

Comment: I am not run exactly your code, but replaced those string array with List, it has the same exception...

Comment: Try removing the wl.photos scope, I'm not sure I saw that one anywhere else, and use exactly the scopes I posted. I think the problem might be there.

Comment: I am actually copying your code, but still failing, can i have your email address? I can send your my project.

Comment: I'm quite sure that'd be against the site rules. Try editing your question with more info so that we can help you solving your problem. If you get a NullReferenceException, post some info about it, is the Exception internal or does VS tells you that one of your variables is null? Is there any external code you have that may be interfering with this one?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get the code working: before running the code, **i have to associate my app in the windows store**, so that in the project, there is one file called Package.StoreAssociation.xml generated.
With authentication, my live account information is retrieved correctly and no exception any more.